# Licensing Software Products on Azure

Tags: azure

We currently have a few products for which the licensing depends on the computer name, the customer enter the computer name to create a license key and uses that license key to license the product on that machine.

For Azure roles, the computer name of a server does not remain constant so the above said method of generating the license key does not work. I am looking into an alternate way of generating the license key for each Azure instance. Instead of using the computer name, is there any other environment variables for Azure instance that I might be able to use to generate the license key?

Perhaps I might be able to use RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance property. Will this property persist if the fabric controller re-images or recreates the instance? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance is probably your best alternative, however, Windows Azure makes no promises or guarantees about spinning up machines named with a proper naming pattern and correct sequencing.
So, it may work this month or next, but in a year from now, when they change naming conventions or sequencing logic, you and your customers will need to do redeploy and in "hot" production environment - because changes in Azure are rolled out every month without big pre-announcements.

In general, this is a tough issue if you insist on marrying license to anything machine-specific in Azure.  Can you find no other way to enforce the copyright?

Comment: So far I have not found anything reliable in azure to make the license key machine or instance specific. We may have to start looking at other ways to enforce the licensing on Azure instances. Thanks for your feedback Igorek!

Answer (score 0):

What Igorek says is perfect, Azure gives no guarantees about the naming convention / pattern. The basis of your requirement for licencing is that that you need atleast 1 parameter to ensure it is the same machine/subscription for licensing, I guess you can you service like [DNS Azure](http://dnsazure.com) and solve your purpose.